# java form button order execution

Tags: java, button, action

i write a method to create a form(3 buttons and a textBox), then i call it in main. 
 but when i run program, before i enter information in the form (method form6 ),
 Other commands that are executed! "s4 and ontname chenged in the form".
this is a part of my code:::::::::::

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("*begin main*"); // call form method
```

String s4= form6(); // s4 is returned by method.
   System.out.println("s3333**"+s4);

   System.out.println("ont*:"+ontname);//it's global }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

i have 2 questions:::

1--- While the form is running, other commands are executed!
 What is their order execution? 
  2. --- i want to define a button to when i click it,it closes the form.

thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your code correctly, `ontname` is either (1) a class member (declared outside a method) or (2) a local variable, which is declared in the method that contains this code snippet.

In both cases there is no need to "return" `ontname` just because it is not declared inside the anonymous ActionListener instance.

The following example illustrates a typical pattern for this problem:

```
public void someMethod() {
  // ...
  button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      String filename = File.separator+"c:";
      JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File(filename));
      fc.showOpenDialog(null);
      File selFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
      setOntName(selFile.getPath());  // <-- here we call another method
    }
  });
  // ...
}

void setOntName(String ontName) {
  // do something with ontName
}
```

Alternativly: declare ontName as a static class member (only):

```
private static String ontName = "";  // <-- accessible from main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // ...
}
// more methods.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a value in this Method because the ActionListenerInterface does not allow this. But you can call another method from within the actionPerformed() method and pass the ontname to it.

You can also close the third button in the new method. Or define the third button as final and use it in the actionPerformed() method.

E.g.

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           String filename = File.separator+"c:";
           JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File(filename));
           fc.showOpenDialog(null);
           File selFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
           ontname=selFile.getPath();
           System.out.println("filepath:  "+ontname); //it works correctly.  
           anotherMethod(ontname);   
         }
      });

private void anotherMethod(String path) {
        //doSomething with the path

        //close third button here
}
```

Comment: thanks all. i understand. i have another problem: i write a method to create a form, then i call it in main. public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("*begin main*"); // call form method String s4= form6(); // print global variables System.out.println("s3333**"+s4); System.out.println("ont*:"+ontname);//it's global } but when i run program, before i enter information in form (method form6 ), Other commands that are executed!                    While the form is running, other commands are executed! What is their order execution? –– fateme.hosseini

Answer (score 0):

You could probably define your variable ontname as global, outside of your function:

```
var ontname = null;
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
// ...
    ontname=selFile.getPath();
  }
});

// ...

System.out.println("filepath:  "+ontname);
```

Comment: thanks anyway. but While the form is running, other commands are executed! "System.out.println("filepath:  "+ontname);" print "null".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remember the values, then they should be class level variables.

But, generally, you would want to pass these to some other method to do some processing on them (or, say, persist them in a file). You can pass these as parameters to the other method.

(The second one is better in most cases, I don't know much about your app, so I am unable to give one answer)

There are other problems with your code:

1. You need to check whether the use has clicked the "Ok" or "Cancel" button in the open dialog to decide whether to get the file or not.
2. `String filename = File.separator+"c:";` does not really make sense. Perhaps you meant `String filename = "c:"+File.separator;` But even this is not very useful. `File.separator` is for getting the platform specific file separator char (`\` in Windows, `/` on linux) but since you are hard coding `c:`, you are anyway constrainting your app to Windows. You might want to have a better platform independent way (start at the "default" path, `new JFileChooser()` without arguments, and then remember the path the user last used, and proceed from there)
3. If the argument to the showOpenDialog method is your parent frame, then the dialog would be centered on the parent frame, and would, in most cases, look nicer.

You might also want to relook your variable names.

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{    
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      String filename = File.separator+"c:";
      JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new File(filename));
      int option = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
      if(option = JFileChooser.APROVE_OPTION)
      {
         File selFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
         String ontname=selFile.getPath();
         System.out.println("filepath: "+ontname); //it works correctly.
         doSomeOperation(ontname); //Or, declare ontname as a class level variable.
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks all. i understand. i have another problem: i write a method to create a form, then i call it in main.                                     public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("*begin main*");
  // call form method
  String s4= form6();
  // print global variables
  System.out.println("s3333**"+s4);
     System.out.println("ont*:"+ontname);//it's global  
 }                          but when i run program, before i enter information in form (method form6 ), Other commands that are executed!

Comment: While the form is running, other commands are executed!                What is their order execution?